# Can I set Airflow variables from inside a DockerOperator?

Tags: docker, airflow

I have a DAG that runs a Docker container using `DockerOperator`. The Docker container runs some Python and shell scripts. Is it possible for these scripts to set an Airflow variable (the ones that show up in `http://localhost:8080/variable/list/`)?

I know that it is possible to pass templated command to the docker like so:

```
t2 = DockerOperator(
        task_id='docker_command',
        image='my_docker:latest',
        auto_remove=True,
        environment={
                'AF_EXECUTION_DATE': "{{ ds }}",
                'AF_OWNER': "{{ task.owner }}"
            }
    )
```

But this would only allow the Docker to read them, not write to them.